# Add component to HTML with Angular 2 bindings

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create an application where an input field is dynamically added to my page.

For that, I currently use the following code (simplified):

Html:

```
<div #content></div>
```

Angular:

```
public class MyPage implements AfterViewInit {
   @ViewChild('content') contentElement: ElementRef;

   content: HtmlElement;

   constructor() {}

   ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.content = this.contentElement.nativeElement;
   }

   addInput() {
     this.content.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<input type="text"/>');
   }

   processInput(event) {
      alert(event.target.value);
   }
}
```

But now I want to do something like this:

```
   addInput() {
     this.content.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<input (keyup.enter)="processInput($event)" type="text"/>`);
   }
```

With the `( )` bindings.

But this just shows when I inspect the page:

- When entered into plain html file:

  `<input type="text"/>`
- When injected from my code:

  `<input type="text (keyup.enter)="processInput($event)"/>`

How can I make this work? I've already tried a workaround to create a different component and handle the `processInput` there and then to just use the `selector`. But this does the exact same, just puts the selector name of the component in the DOM but not the actual component.

**tl;dr**

Just imagine that I want to add an input field where the enter command listens to the `processInput`, not that hard. But now I want to insert these input fields from my angular code.

Adding Angular based stuff, like `[]`, `()` to HTML doesn't work/doesn't get compiled

Comment: Don't do so. Use component approach

Comment: I'll need to dynamically add input's with the corresponding `processInput` being fired on `keyup.enter`. Any idea how I would do this with the component approach?

Comment: You can try using `ngFor` or more low-level API like `createEmbeddedView, createComponent` https://plnkr.co/edit/G6R6N8VMHMAZE1scJqfG?p=preview

Comment: The problem I encounter with your plnkr is that it creates the component after the `div` is it possible to just append it?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/C8Gp8u3tgeKgkH2gZ0e8?p=preview